# c socket multiple calls to read

Tags: c++, c, sockets, tcp

I am writing 3200 floats like so:

```
float fft[3200] = {0};
get_fft_frame(dev, fft, 3200); // rf sensor
int written = write(sd, fft, sizeof(fft));
```

and reading then like this:

```
float *fft = new float[3200];
int inRead = 0;
while (inRead < (3200*4)) {
    //sleep(1);
    int bytesRead = read(sd, fft + inRead, (3200*4) - inRead);
    inRead += bytesRead;
}
```

All the data is written in 1 write but it takes two read calls to get all the data. The first read returns 11584 and the second returns 1216.

The problem is that the second read call just reads zeros. However if I uncomment the sleep call, it reads all the correct data.

Is there a better way to get the data without sleeping?

Comment: Do you have to use a socket, or can you use other forms of process communication? Pipes could be what you are looking for because they block.

Comment: You need to show us how the socket has been set up. That is, provide a [mcve]. But for starters you need to check the return value of `read`. `read` can return `-1` on error and in that case you should not be adding that to `inRead`. If implemented correctly there should be no issue with multiple `read` calls. So thus we need to see *complete* code.

Comment: Yes, I am already to deep into the project for a re-factor like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing up your offsets. `inRead` is measured in bytes, but when you add it to `fft` it is multiplied by `sizeof float` by the rules of pointer arithmetic. The offset expression in the `read()` call should be

```
((char*)fft)+inRead
```